# users in groups, groups have privileges, does EJB 3 support this model with annotations?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am interested in utilising EJB 3's security annotations for our company's security model. As stated in the question title: users are a part of groups and each group has assigned a list of privileges, this allows privileges to be dynamically allocated to groups without effecting group membership.

However, as far as i can see, EJB 3.x only supports the User --> Roles|groups model (virtually the same where groups are treated as roles).

What i am aiming for is something along the lines of:...

```
@Stateless
public class secureEJB {
    ...
    @HasPrivilege(Privileges.ABLE_TO_MAKE_ARBITRARY_DATABASE_CHANGES)
    public void causeMayhem();
    ...
}
```

If EJB 3 does not support this model then does anyone know of a library to support this?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EJB perspective/view/interface/specification only consists of users and roles. EJB does not define the way this data is *maintained*. Roles are used to enforce authorization.

So you can setup whatever model you like to maintain authentication/authorization data. For example users are group members, and permissions are attached to groups.

For example, using JBoss, it's the task of a `LoginModule` to return the roles of a given user. In case of the `DatabaseServerLoginModule` you can use a SQL statment to join together users, their groups, and the group/roles assignments. The result is always just a plain list of roles. As for WebSphere, they use the name "Custom user registry" instead of "Login module".

There are some options to build the back end:

- As the user is frequently part of a data model of an application (with referential integrity being enforced by constraints) it's often integrated it into the data model of the application.
- If this is not required (or even not wanted), you can integrate whatever you like. In that case look at a solution like a portal (Liferay for example), as this provides a data model, maintenenance application, password reset, Email verification, lockout handling, Single sign on (SSO) integration etc. The authorization data model is not the problem; it's rather the need for a user interface to maintain the data.